# php mechanism behind loading multiple files

Tags: php, html

I'm doing a multiple file upload form and i've succeeded in making it with the help of this site. Now i need to know and understand how it works so i can don't just copy code.

We have an input for upload in HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />
```

And all is saved in a php variable:

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]
```

How do the brackets in name="file[]" create a 3rd dimension to a array like this? I would rather imagine something in the line of: $_FILES['file[$i]']['tmp_name']. And why doesn't it work without them anyway?
Thank you!

Comment: `$_FILES` is already populated with two dimensions, if the HTML form field is not an array. If you make your HTML input field to be an array as well, PHP adds the 3rd dimension in terms of counters. Having a count reference in terms of `[$file[$i]]` makes no sense when you think about it. You can't pull meaningful data out of it nor does it make sense.

Comment: True. I guess i didn't think that trough. But i need to know why "name[]" works and "name" not

Comment: Should have written something like $_FILES['file['.$i.']'][]. (Sorry for double comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows the schema of all other names: if you append `[]` to a name, PHP will create an array for you. It's that simple.

```
/foo.php?bar[]=baz&bar[]=42
```

This will result in:

```
$_GET['bar'][0] = 'baz'
$_GET['bar'][1] = '42'
```

The same for form inputs:

```
<input name="foo[]">
```

This will create a multidimensional `$_POST` array:

```
$_POST['foo'][..]
```

The only difference with `$_FILES` is that the structure is slightly unintuitive. It's not:

```
$_FILES['foo'][0]['tmp_name']
$_FILES['foo'][0]['name']
$_FILES['foo'][1]['tmp_name']
$_FILES['foo'][1]['name']
...
```

But instead it's:

```
$_FILES['foo']['tmp_name'][0]
$_FILES['foo']['name'][0]
$_FILES['foo']['tmp_name'][1]
$_FILES['foo']['name'][1]
```

That's just the way it is. Yes, this API could have been designed better, but then so could have been a lot of PHP.

Comment: PHP is designed perfectly, that's why everybody loves it! </joke>

Comment: PHP is designed </joke>

Answer (score 0):

Since you're uploading (possible) multiple Files, there must be a way to save them correctly.

So the System goes like this:

```
$_FILES: 
The superglobal where the FILES will be saved
```

```
['file']: 
In this array the actual FILEDATA will be saved.
Another possibilty at this localtion would be ['error'], 
where outcoming error within the upload will be stored.
```

```
['tmp_name']:
Here you can access all the file names that were uploaded
Another possibilty on this possition would be ['type'],
where the type of the file will be stored (e.g. 'text/html')
```

```
[$i] is there to identify the exact file you within the uploaded files.
```

Take from [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) here is an example:

```
array(1) {
    ["files"]=>array(2) {
        ["tmp_name"]=>array(2) {
            [0]=>string(9)"file0.txt"
            [1]=>string(9)"file1.txt"
        }
        ["type"]=>array(2) {
            [0]=>string(10)"text/plain"
            [1]=>string(10)"text/html"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it is clear and understandable!

Comment: It is clear and understandable, but those are things i know. Thank you anyway, it's a nice mind update. :D